# Duda sobre ruta en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estimados desarrolladores buen día, tengo una duda técnica conforme a una aplicación de consola hecha en C#, resulta que hace los procesos como debe en general y cuando hay un error los envía por correo, hace todo perfecto. está en productivo. Pero resulta que las veces que hay algun error (Latencia, seguridad, etc) envía el tipo de error PERO además envía mi ruta. y en ninguna parte del código aparece mi ruta, ésto puede llevar a confusión del usuario pero no encuentro donde podria estar mi ruta en el código que aparece en el mensaje de error.
Ejemplo de Mail error enviado:

> This message is from an EXTERNAL SENDER - be CAUTIOUS, particularly with links and attachments.
>
> Error en ejecucion tarea Movimientos de tipo ------    System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. 
>      at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(Uri address, String method, NameValueCollection data) 
>      at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(String address, NameValueCollection data)

y ACA  se puede ver mi ruta

> at Movimientos_Centrales.CookieAwareWebClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\joeldocuments\visual studio 2015\Projects\Movimientos\Movimientos\Program.cs:line 731

Answer (score 1):

Esto es absolutamente normal. Las rutas del código fuente quedan almacenadas en los archivos [`PDB`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2017), como es lógico ya que hacen referencia al código fuente, que no se encuentra presente probablemente en el equipo que tiene tu aplicación instalada.

No hay forma de evitar esto, a no ser que hagas una compilación en `Release` en lugar de en `Debug`.

Answer (score 0):

La ruta tiene que ver con la compilacion en `debug` para que encuentres el problema ante un error.

Para que esta no aparezca deberias compilar en `release`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]